# Dont want scroll bar in datagrid but in outer container

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have a datagrid with more than 70 columns (with few fixed). I dont want the scrollbar to appear in datagrid (both horizontal and vertical) but in the parent container which is a VBox (or canvas) instead.  This will help to scroll the screen vertically without having to scroll all the way right in datagird to scroll vertically. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Wrapped the datagrid inside a VBox with its height and width as 100% and then set the width and height of datagrid (at runtime) as little less than its parent container's width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Jus take out the scrollable policy..horizontal..vertical...and if u using padding in top and bottom take that too... and keep only...`

```
height ="100%" widht="100%"
```

I hope this part is enough... will works Fine and Good Dude! CheckOut.....!